# Getting a completed HTML web form with populated data from a browser into an email or PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, screen-scraping

I have an HTML web form that is dynamically completed by the user entering a serial number, javascript and php code then retrieves data from a server-based SQL database and updates the form fields with the retrieved information.

When the user clicks a Submit button on the HTML form I want to be able to automatically replicate what is displayed on the screen (including the retrieved data) into an email (or alternatively a PDF file that I can then email).

I have found solutions that get the base web form but haven't found something that can "screenscrape" the completed form as displayed by the browser.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Many thanks in advance.
...Steve

Comment: There's no way for the server to know what the browser is showing. Your best bet is generally going to be to capture the HTML page that the application generates on the server side (or regenerate a new similar page) and then use that as an attachment for an email. Your ability to do this is going to be highly dependent on your application design.

Comment: @alex howansky Thanks Alex. Making it server side would be an option. I was hoping to avoid having to 'rebuild' the form on the server side as I've already created the completed version at the client side.

Comment: It is possible to do that client side with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) but this approach does come with some caveats and is not recommended for production usage (as documentation says).

Generating the pdf on server is the better approach. As for the tools, you can generate a pdf file server-side using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which has a [php wrapper](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf) you can use in your code. You will need to render your html template with the data you want before that.

Comment: @avio Thank you. I have played with htmlcanvas and it wasn't the best solution. Both yours and Alex's need the form to be recreated server side so I will look more into doing that, thank you. Thanks also for the wkhtmltopdf recommendation - I'll check it out.

Comment: Just wondering why the question has been down-scored? Is it not a valid question?

Comment: If your app observes MVC and uses a templating system then it should take like two lines of code -- just render the template again, capture the output, and send it to a mailer. If your app is a monolithic legacy amalgamation, well... good luck. Also note that there's no need to mess with PDF, just send an HTML email.

Comment: @Alex I'm not using MVC - this is just a relatively simple form and client/server application and I'm not a 'professional' developer:-)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say after you fill in your form the result goes to

```
http://www.example.com/invoices/download/result.html
```

You can do the following to take the curl response in html to pdf.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/invoices/download/result.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

header('Cache-Control: public'); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_file.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you @unixmiah. I'll give this a try over the next few days.